# What raid pass will be used if I (physically) move whilst being in the lobby?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you join a raid lobby, you select which pass you are using (remote, daily or premium). The pass will actually not be used until the raid starts. Can the type of pass change based on your physical movement while in the raid lobby?

For example, if I walk towards the gym and start the raid lobby outside of the normal range (so with a remote pass) but the raid starts when I am in range (so the daily free pass could be used), would I use the remote pass or the daily pass? And the other way around, can I start the raid lobby when inside range, and already start walking home again?

Of course, when there is a larger group I could start the lobby with any pass, go out and rejoin when in range. But in those cases I don't mind the spent a couple of minutes outside, chitchatting. It is mostly for the 1* or 3* raids that you can solo, and want to spend as little time as possible (while using the least expensive pass).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've casually tested this, by joining raids in range to use a daily free pass and then walked home while in the lobby. It always used the raid pass that was displayed when I joined the raid lobby, despite the fact that the raid passes aren't consumed until the battle starts and no matter how far I'd gotten from the raid location.

Note: If you trigger the "going too fast" screen (by driving away instead of walking) before the battle starts, the raid may kick you out and still consume the raid pass. So I guess there's effectively a soft-cap on how far you can get from a gym in a raid.

Comment: Does it still consume the pass now, since they changed the passes to be consumed when you start the battle instead of upon joining the lobby?

Comment: @Joe If you're referring to my second paragraph, yes. The pass is consumed when you enter the battle before the speed check happens, so you can get kicked and lose the pass. Luckily, if you were kicked in error, you can re-lobby for free since using a raid pass allows as many attempts as you want until you win.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. That’s what I meant.

Comment: Huh, so I can use my daily free pass and then walk away now. It used to be that you were kicked out of the battle for being too far away if you were out of range when the battle started (you could always walk away *during* the battle afaik)